# Flutter: how can I block on an async call from a synchronous method?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I've got a Dart class with the synchronous method `bool doLogin(String username, String password)`.

`doLogin()` calls internal method `_queryServer()`, which in turn calls `http.Response response = await http.post()`.

"_queryServer()" needs to be async, in order to use "await" (or use ".then()").  "doLogin()" must *NOT* be async.

Q: How do I structure my code such that doLogin() doesn't return until _queryServer() has a response (or a failure)?

My code looks something like this:

```
  ...
  Future<void> _queryServer  (username, password) async {
    final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    Map<String, dynamic> logonRequest = {
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    };
    String jsonPayload = jsonEncode(logonRequest);
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("https://myserver/login"),
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonPayload,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _isAuthorized = true;
    }
  }
  ...
  bool login(String username, String password)  {
    _queryServer(username, password);
    // Q: How do I block until _queryServer() completes?
    return _isAuthorized;
  }
```

Comment: There is no supported way to do that. `login` should be made asynchronous (and its callers, and so on).

Comment: That's exactly the problem.  I CANNOT make login async.  Much less its callers, and so on...  Q: Maybe Flutter has a class that can make an HTTP "post" synchronously?

Comment: If you can't make `login` properly asynchronous (why not?) then you instead will need to provide a separate API for callers to check (and possibly be notified) when the query is complete.